# How can I change the color of a label depending on if isEnabled is true or false?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code in a template that I am using, but it's not able to work because of this message:

[image: ErrorMessage]

I understand why the message is present but I do not know how to fix this so that the label color depends on the state of the isEnabled.

```
namespace Templates
{
    public class LinkLabel : Label
    {
        public LinkLabel()
        {
            this.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "Default-Regular");
            this.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontSizeProperty,   "LabelTextFontSize");
            this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty,  "LinkLabelColor");
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        }

        public static BindableProperty IsEnabledProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsDisabled), typeof(bool), typeof(LinkLabel), default(bool), propertyChanged: IsEnabledPropertyPropertyChanged);

        public bool IsDisabled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void IsEnabledPropertyPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if ((bool)newValue)
            {
                LinkLabel label = bindable as LinkLabel;
                label.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelDisabledColor");
            }
            else
            {
                LinkLabel label = bindable as LinkLabel;
                label.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelColor");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like BoolToColor [converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters)? So you can set in xaml: color="{Binding boolvalue, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"

Comment: Not really.  I am looking for a C# solution to setting the color based on the isEnabled property value.

Comment: "public static BindableProperty MyEnabledProperty", "BindingContext = this;" and in xaml set: IsEnable="{Binding MyEnabled}". Like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we check the source code of class **VisualElement** , we will find that there is already a bindable property called **IsEnabledProperty** . As **VisualElement** is the super class of most of UI Elements . So there will be  ambiguity between the two  `IsEnabledProperty` .

[image]

**Solution 1:**

The easiest way is modify the name of the bindable property like **IsDisabledProperty**

**Solution 2:**

Since there is already a **IsEnabledProperty** in the Label . We could set the value in xaml and handle the logic in code behind like

```
public class LinkLabel : Label
{
    public LinkLabel()
    {
        this.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "Default-Regular");
        this.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontSizeProperty, "LabelTextFontSize");
        this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelColor");
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;

        this.PropertyChanged += LinkLabel_PropertyChanged;

    }

    private void LinkLabel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       
        if(e.PropertyName== "IsEnabled")
        {
            var label = sender as LinkLabel;
            var newValue = label.IsEnabled;

            if ((bool)newValue)
            {
              
                this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelDisabledColor");
            }
            else
            {

                this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelColor");
            }

        }

    }
```